# Docker 'is not an absolute path or is a symlink' error

Tags: docker

I start docker at private cloud host and get next error

```
sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/83d55d497417883ea85b63ebe3138e5f5dbc2b3c8b2db663c1a007e7af1757f1/merged 
is not an absolute path or is a symlink: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

ll shows next

```
ll /var/lib/docker/overlay2                             
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jun 19 15:32 /var/lib/docker/overlay2 -> /dev/docker-overlay2/
```

Are there any way to fix it ?

Comment: try `sudo docker ....` ?

Comment: can you remove that symlink and try again.

Comment: I have found next thread 
https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-change-var-lib-docker-directory-with-overlay2/43620/6
with something similar

Comment: What you were trying to achieve, do you want `/dev/docker-overlay2/` to hold all docker related data rather than `/var/lib/docker` ?

Comment: The error says `or is a symlink`, and you've done your `ll` on a symbolic link

Answer (score 30):

I met this problem, I restart docker service, solve it

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: No idea why, but this fixed it.

Comment: I had moved /var/lib/docker to a difference location (on a drive that had more space) and created a symlinks. Then I got this error. Restarting docker process fixed it

Answer (score 3):

problem was that someone configured symlink for "fat" directory with images to move it to another disc. Instead of properly configuring in /etc/docker/daemon.json

Comment: For me symlink works, but I needed restart docker service: 
`systemctl restart docker`